# In a Powershell script, what does a period in a file path actually do?

Tags: windows, powershell

Say you have the following line in your powershell script:

```
"Foo" >> .\test.txt
```

What directory does test.txt get sent to?  Is it the current directory of the shell which called the script, or is there an environment variable that it uses?

Comment: Depending on how it's being used, it stands for other things as well. In your case it means current directory. In other cases such as: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName . -ScriptBlock {....` it means your local computer. You can thank Powershells token analyzer (*lexical analyzer*) for this(:

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Windows for a long time now, however I think, this is similar to unix-like paths, where the dot represents current directory.
So in your situation, `... >> .\test.txt` is the same as `... >> test.txt`.

A small difference to original unix paths, is that they use a normal slash, e.g. `... >> ./test.txt`

Comment: Besides that, there are two more scenarios that I know of.
1. "Dot importing" other PowerShell scripts. `. <dir>/script.ps1`
2. Executing a script block: `.{1 + 1}` => 2

Comment: But what is the current directory?  Is it the directory that the script is in? Is it the directory of the shell that ran the script?  What if you're running the script through a GUI? Is there some special system variable that holds the current directory?

Comment: That variable is normally %cd%, and it is transscribed as "current directory", normally it is the path you are calling your script from